# How can I set a Core Data property based on another Core Data property when saving?

Tags: core-data, swift3

I want to update a Core Data property on an Entity when another property on the same Entity is set/changed... The property has to be set in the database (not Transient?) while I'm using it when requesting and sorting data (don't want to generate it on the fly - to avoid memory consumption).

My autogenerated Core Data extension for my Entity is show below and is called 'MyObject' (*+CoreDataProperties.swift)

```
extension MyObject {
  ::
  @NSManaged public var number: String?
  @NSManaged public var numberRaw: Int64
  ::
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to set the the property of 'numberRaw' whenever the 'number' property is set in my own extension - overriding does not seems to be possible(?).

```
extension MyObject {
  private var dummy: Int64 {
    get {
        self.willAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.numberRaw))
        let number = self.primitiveValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.numberRaw)) as? Int64
        self.didAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.numberRaw))
        return number
    }
    set {
        self.willAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.number))
        let number = self.primitiveValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.number)) as! String!
        self.didAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.number))

        self.willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.numberRaw))
        var value: Int64 = 0
        if let digits = number?.digits, digits.isEmpty == false {
            value = Int64(digits)!
        }
        self.setPrimitiveValue(value, forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.numberRaw))
        self.didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(MyObject.numberRaw))
    }
  }
}
```

(I'm not referring the 'dummy' object in the code.)

Only the 'number' property is set/changed. The 'numberRaw' property is just read (code and NSFetchRequest).

Comment: Implementing custom accessors is definitely possible. What did you try (or is your `private var dummy` the code you used), and what specifically went wrong?

Comment: The `private var dummy` does not set the 'numberRaw' value when a row is saved in the database. Overriding gives me an build error (the property is already set in the model)